# 2008 Yamaha Zuma won’t start

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, yamaha

Will not turn over unless I cover the air intake on the carb with my hand. Fuel gets sucked in and it runs until there is no more fuel. It’s not getting fuel by itself.

Comment: It sounds as if the carb has a clogged jet.  When you cover the intake you put additional vacuum, much like applying the choke, and you get fuel past the clog.  You may be able to clean it but it will take disassembling the carb.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Cleaned the carb and Jets.... does the Pilot Jet supposed to allow fuel through it like the main jet? It looks like a metal check valve but really small to see.

Comment: Took carb completely apart and cleaned thoroughly and I still need to put my hand over the air intake to get fuel into the venturi.   Take my hand off and no gas. Any guesses?